# app.showMessage promise .then fails in HotTowel durandal SPA

Tags: modal-dialog, breeze, durandal, promise, hottowel

Has anyone experienced this, or is able to point me in the right direction:

I'm using code from John Papa's hottowel SPA template.  My modal dialog won't close after attempting to cancel changes, using:

```
  var canDeactivate = function () {
    if (isDeleting()) { return false; }

    if (hasChanges()) {
        var title = 'Do you want to leave "' +
            projectDetails()[0].title() + '" ?';
        var msg = 'Navigate away and cancel your changes?';

        return app.showMessage(title, msg, ['Yes', 'No'])
        .then(confirm);

        function confirm(selectedOption)
        {
            if (selectedOption === 'Yes') {
                cancel();
            }

            return selectedOption;
        }

    }
    return true;
};
```

I get:

TypeError: activator.deactivateItem(...).then is not a function
[Break On This Error]

and a reference to line 72 of Durandal's modalDialog.js:

activator.deactivateItem(instance, true).then(function (closeSuccess) {.....

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had some additional code from the template for the HotTowel main.js:

```
// Q shim
    system.defer = function (action) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    action.call(deferred, deferred);
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    deferred.promise = function () {
        return promise;
    };

    return deferred;
    };
```

This shim was causing the error - don't know why but hope this helps someone...

Comment: Jeremy, it's not clear whether you needed to add, delete or modify the "shim".

Comment: I deleted it.  The funny thing is, it's not in HotTowel on github, and I didn't write it, so I don't know where it came from!

Comment: Ooh, an ethereal vapour shim. They're definitely the worst.

Answer (score 0):

`canDeactivate()` appears to return either a boolean or a promise.

Typically you would expect such a function always to return a promise or always to return a boolean, otherwise the calling function will have difficulty handling the returned value.

I expect your calling function expects either a boolean or a promise, and throws an error when the other is delivered.

Comment: See my answer - a shim for Q.js was the problem - not sure whether it's related to your point but thanks for your response Beetroot.